# facedetect.cpp to detect eye in a cropped image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, face-detection

I am using OpenCV for face and eye detection. To start with, I tested the sample program in OpenCV/Samples/c/facedetect.cpp. I gave two images as an input to this facedetect.exe - one is full and the other is cropped face of the same person. Now, the facedetect.cpp works fine with full image whereas it is not even detecting the face with the cropped image as input.

Although the cropped image contains only the face which is cropped using OpenCV face detector, In some bad cases I will get only mouth or lips or only part of the face. So my requirement here is to check both the eyes are there in an image or not.

The below are the two sample pictures one is full image where I get proper output:
[image]

The below is the image where I need to detect the eyes using facedetect.cpp:

[image]

So my question here is how to detect the eyes in the cropped image?

The below is the code of sample facedetect.cpp

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates the cascade recognizer. Now you can use Haar or LBP features.\n"
            "This classifier can recognize many ~rigid objects, it's most known use is for faces.\n"
            "Usage:\n"
            "./facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path> this is the primary trained classifier such as frontal face]\n"
               "   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path this an optional secondary classifier such as eyes]]\n"
               "   [--scale=<image scale greater or equal to 1, try 1.3 for example>\n"
               "   [filename|camera_index]\n\n"
            "see facedetect.cmd for one call:\n"
            "./facedetect --cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml\" --nested-cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml\" --scale=1.3 \n"
            "Hit any key to quit.\n"
            "Using OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << "\n" << endl;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale);

String cascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String nestedCascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;
    const String scaleOpt = "--scale=";
    size_t scaleOptLen = scaleOpt.length();
    const String cascadeOpt = "--cascade=";
    size_t cascadeOptLen = cascadeOpt.length();
    const String nestedCascadeOpt = "--nested-cascade";
    size_t nestedCascadeOptLen = nestedCascadeOpt.length();
    String inputName;

    help();

    CascadeClassifier cascade, nestedCascade;
    double scale = 1;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Processing " << i << " " <<  argv[i] << endl;
        if( cascadeOpt.compare( 0, cascadeOptLen, argv[i], cascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            cascadeName.assign( argv[i] + cascadeOptLen );
            cout << "  from which we have cascadeName= " << cascadeName << endl;
        }
        else if( nestedCascadeOpt.compare( 0, nestedCascadeOptLen, argv[i], nestedCascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( argv[i][nestedCascadeOpt.length()] == '=' )
                nestedCascadeName.assign( argv[i] + nestedCascadeOpt.length() + 1 );
            if( !nestedCascade.load( nestedCascadeName ) )
                cerr << "WARNING: Could not load classifier cascade for nested objects" << endl;
        }
        else if( scaleOpt.compare( 0, scaleOptLen, argv[i], scaleOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( !sscanf( argv[i] + scaleOpt.length(), "%lf", &scale ) || scale < 1 )
                scale = 1;
            cout << " from which we read scale = " << scale << endl;
        }
        else if( argv[i][0] == '-' )
        {
            cerr << "WARNING: Unknown option %s" << argv[i] << endl;
        }
        else
            inputName.assign( argv[i] );
    }

    if( !cascade.load( cascadeName ) )
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade" << endl;
        cerr << "Usage: facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path>]\n"
            "   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path]]\n"
            "   [--scale[=<image scale>\n"
            "   [filename|camera_index]\n" << endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    if( inputName.empty() || (isdigit(inputName.c_str()[0]) && inputName.c_str()[1] == '\0') )
    {
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' );
        int c = inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' ;
        if(!capture) cout << "Capture from CAM " <<  c << " didn't work" << endl;
    }
    else if( inputName.size() )
    {
        image = imread( inputName, 1 );
        if( image.empty() )
        {
            capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( inputName.c_str() );
            if(!capture) cout << "Capture from AVI didn't work" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        image = imread( "lena.jpg", 1 );
        if(image.empty()) cout << "Couldn't read lena.jpg" << endl;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    if( capture )
    {
        cout << "In capture ..." << endl;
        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            detectAndDraw( frameCopy, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                goto _cleanup_;
        }

        waitKey(0);

_cleanup_:
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "In image read" << endl;
        if( !image.empty() )
        {
            detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
            waitKey(0);
        }
        else if( !inputName.empty() )
        {
            /* assume it is a text file containing the
            list of the image filenames to be processed - one per line */
            FILE* f = fopen( inputName.c_str(), "rt" );
            if( f )
            {
                char buf[1000+1];
                while( fgets( buf, 1000, f ) )
                {
                    int len = (int)strlen(buf), c;
                    while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]) )
                        len--;
                    buf[len] = '\0';
                    cout << "file " << buf << endl;
                    image = imread( buf, 1 );
                    if( !image.empty() )
                    {
                        detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
                        c = waitKey(0);
                        if( c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q' )
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cerr << "Aw snap, couldn't read image " << buf << endl;
                    }
                }
                fclose(f);
            }
        }
    }

    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    return 0;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale)
{
    int i = 0;
    double t = 0;
    vector<Rect> faces;
    const static Scalar colors[] =  { CV_RGB(0,0,255),
        CV_RGB(0,128,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,128,0),
        CV_RGB(255,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,255)} ;
    Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );

    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR );
    equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg );

    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces,
        1.1, 2, 0
        //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
        //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
        |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        ,
        Size(30, 30) );
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    printf( "detection time = %g ms\n", t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );
    for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++, i++ )
    {
        Mat smallImgROI;
        vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
        Point center;
        Scalar color = colors[i%8];
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
        center.y = cvRound((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
        radius = cvRound((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
        circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        if( nestedCascade.empty() )
            continue;
        smallImgROI = smallImg(*r);
        nestedCascade.detectMultiScale( smallImgROI, nestedObjects,
            1.1, 2, 0
            //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
            |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            ,
            Size(30, 30) );
        for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator nr = nestedObjects.begin(); nr != nestedObjects.end(); nr++ )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + nr->x + nr->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + nr->y + nr->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((nr->width + nr->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    cv::imshow( "result", img );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original example detects faces first by `cascade.detectMultiScale`, then finds eyes in the detected faces by `nestedCascade.detectMultiScale`.

If you only need to detect the eyes, just use `nestedCascade.detectMultiScale` on the full image.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a detected face (frontal face) a rough positions of the left and right eye regions are then estimated using anthropometric relations as show below.
[image][image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. +1 for the way it is presented. My intension here is not to locate the eye but to confirm the presence of  eye in a cropped image. I intend to do this to confirm whether the cropping has been done properly by my face detect program. Hope you get me now? Again a great thnks for your response...

Comment: After that you can do some kind of circle detection or ellipse detection.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cascade classifier name:

```
String cascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

change this to

```
String cascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
```

and pass the location of the image as the argument.